# What is INT_MAX in Dijkstra's Algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dijkstra

I'm trying to implement Dijkstra's, algorithm, and I have a pretty good grasp of how to do it on a fundamental level, but one thing that's confusing me is INT_MAX. Here's the algorithm I'm following:

```
Dijkstra(start, end)
     startV = search(start)
     endV = search(end)
     startV.solved = true
     startV.distance = 0
     solved = {startV} //list of solved vertices
     while (!endV.solved)
         minDistance = INT_MAX
         solvedV = NULL
         for s in solved
            for y in s.adjacent
              if(!y.solved)
                  dist = s.distance + y.distance
                  if(dist < minDistance)
                      solvedV = y
                      minDistance = dist
                      parent = s
     solvedV.distance = minDistance
     solvedV.parent = parent
     solvedV.solved = true

     solved.add(solvedV)
```

Why would something called the minDistance be calculated using something called INT_MAX if you're trying to find the shortest path? And how do you find INT_MAX? If it affects the answer at all, I'm using C++ and my vertices are structs. But it is for homework, so no code for answers, please.

Comment: `INT_MAX` means the maximum possible integer.

Comment: To see why it is used here, run through this algorithm on paper (or in  a debugger if you have a coded version of it) and watch what happens to the value of `minDistance` as the algorithm progresses

Comment: why not hammer that name into Google?

Comment: Initializing a minimum to the maximum or vice versa is a common idiom. It's not complicated, just think about what would happen if you initialized `minDistance` to something very small.

Comment: @The Paramagnetic Croissant I did, and I didn't find anything useful. @harold, do you mean to say that `minDistance` is  type of boundary, just an arbitrary large number?

Comment: It's simply that `minDistance` tracks the minimum found so far, so you initialize it with something that **can't** be the minimum to ensure that it will get appropriately updated.

Comment: @MichaelBurr that is the answer I was looking for, thanks! Would an appropriate INT_MAX be the sum of the edge weights? Not that really matters in my case, but is that a typical approach?

Comment: You "didn't find anything useful"? Googling `INT_MAX` [literally tells you the answer](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22int_max%22). Come on.

Comment: You know, I didn't realize that `INT_MAX` was an existing keyword with no special significant meaning to the algorithm, which is where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`INT_MAX` is a constant that represents the highest possible value that an `int` can store.
It is found in "limits.h"
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/

When you want to find the shortest distance of something, you want to compare the currently evaluated distance with the shortest distance you've found "so far", and see if you've found a shorter one.
This usually involves starting with the **longest** possible distance as a temporary starting point, so that any distance you find will automatically be shorter.

As you can see, further down, there is a statement, `if (dist < minDistance)`, which will always be `true` the **first** time, since any valid distance is effectively guaranteed to be shorter than the maximum possible distance value, `INT_MAX`.

The same idea is used in many similar algorithms where you want to find the highest or lowest value: We initialize to the worst possible value (contextually), so that the first valid value found will be accepted.

Consider what would happen if we didn't write `INT_MAX`, but some other, lower number. The consequence is that you would have entered what amounts to a fake value that will effectively **compete with the real values** that you're testing for. Therefore, you always want the initial "fake" value to be guaranteed to fail a comparison with any real value.

Furthermore, if at the end of the algorithm the shortest distance found is still equal to `INT_MAX`, then you know that the function/algorithm found no valid distances at all. For example, the function might simply return `minDistance`, and nothing else, and then the caller can check to see it if is equal to `INT_MAX` to know whether the function succeeded or not. (I'm not implying that this would be the best design.)

```
const int result(getMinDistance(whatever));
if (result == INT_MAX) // no real "minDistance" was actually found.
else ... // found some real "minDistance" value.
```